# Is it possible to simplify geometry only for polygons with certain attributes?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, simplify

I have a map of electoral districts. Urban areas have more densely packed districts whose borders are more important to keep at high resolution. More rural districts have simpler geometries and have border details which are less important. I'd like to reduce the number of vertices where I can but keep a higher resolution in urban areas. Is this possible?

Comment: The answer to you question is yes.  New attribute "Urban" fill with 1 for Urban, 0 for Rural, filter Rural, simplify geom.

Comment: Be careful here as you risk destroying any implicit topology.  Within this in mind I'd reconsider whether you really need to do this operation.

Comment: The topology issue occurred to me. I'll have to do some testing. Thanks.